# Algorithm for sorting and pairing elements of 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to configure an efficient algorithm (faster than O(n^2)) for sorting and pairing elements between 2 arrays. However this needs to work under the premise that neither array's elements can be compared to other elements in their own array.

Edit: The elements of the arrays are "sizes" which correspond to particular objects. The idea is that two parts of the same size will fit together. If we were to call the parts screws and holes a screw will only fit in a hole of the same size. However we cannot compare holes to holes or screws to screws for the purpose of this algorithm.

So I am trying to find an algorithm that will best pair together these elements of screw and hole sizes and sort them without comparing an element to elements in the same array.

Re-edit: When two elements are compared from the array we are able to know whether the screw is bigger or smaller than the hole it is compared to.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does "sorting and pairing between 2 arrays" mean? And how do you sort, if you cannot compare inside one array?

Comment: Also, you'll get much better answers if you provide some context. Why do you have these particular constraints?

Comment: You might to put a bit more informations into your question: How should the result be sorting (by what property, if you can't compare the arrayelements to each other). And how should the elements be paired (each of array A with one of array B, or with several? Whats the pairing based on? random? some shared property?...). As it is the question is way to generic to give a useful answer

Comment: updated with a little better clarification.

Comment: Sure you don't need something like a simple HashMap?

Comment: I'm still not really sure what you mean. So has every arrayelement exectly one partner in the other array, or might some have more then one potential partner or can some have none? Besides you still haven't clarified the sorting. To me it seems like you want only to find the pairing instead of needing a sorted result, but thats still unclear (and so far it seems you could compareelements by "size" (or address using a hashmap or something like that), you might want a better analogy/more information about what you are actually doing)

Comment: the final result of the algorithm is an array containing the pairs in order increasing size. I am not concerned with the exact code for this... i am concerned with the idea behind it..

Comment: @Aelos - please address the points in my answer ... if you want me to bother continuing to spend time on your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Revised**

Suppose that we can get one of the three outcomes when we try to fit a screw into a hole:

1. The screw is too small for the hole, such that the screw becomes loose and falls out.
2. The screw fits the hole exactly.
3. The screw is too big for the hole.

**Divide-and-conquer solution.**

- Stage #1

  1. Pick one screw.
  2. Use this screw to test through all holes. (requires N trials)

     - This partitions all holes into one of three cases:

       1. The hole is bigger than the test screw (A).
       2. The hole is the same size as the test screw (B).
       3. The hole is smaller than the test screw (C).
  3. Use the hole which has the same size (chosen from B) to test through all screws. (requires N trials)

     - This partitions all screws into one of three cases:

       1. The screw is bigger than the test hole (D).
       2. The screw is the same size as the test hole (E).
       3. The screw is smaller than the test hole (F).
     - Result:

       1. Any hole picked from B will fit any screw picked from E. This will be the "Pivot" of the partition. They do not require any further testing.
       2. The holes in set A and the screws in set D have diameters wider than the pivot. The holes in set C and the screws in set F have diameters narrower than the pivot.
       3. Thus, we successfully partitioned the initial problem into two smaller problems.

**Analysis**

- Average case: `O(N log N)`
- Worst case: `O(N^2)` because we do not know the rank of the pivot until we have finished partitioning the set using the pivot. Same analysis as *QuickSort*.

**About a variant of the question**

There is a variant of the question in which it's not possible to distinguish between loose-fit with exact fit. That is, for each test only two outcomes are possible:

- hole `<` screw
- hole `>=` screw

This variant is  much much harder. I do not know if it can be solved in `O(n log n)` or not. **(Edited)**

Comment: Yea ... but this will be `O(N^2)` won't it?

Comment: @Stephen: Sorry my old answer was wrong. However, there is in fact a divide-and-conquer algorithm for it, and it will be less than `O(N^2)`, but it was difficult to calculate.

Comment: I rewrote the answer to remove the mistake. The new answer applies to the trichotomy case.

Comment: Randomizing the pivot for this would make the worst case O(nlogn) would it not?

Comment: Randomizing the pivot does not affect the worst case. (After all, what does *worst case* mean?) Unfortunately, the [median-of-three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) method does not work because the pivots (in this case, three nuts or three bolts) can't be compared among themselves.

Comment: In the case of quicksort randomizing the pivot decreases the worst case to O(n log n). I don't see why this case would be any different.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot compare "screws" with other "screws" or "holes" with other "holes", then neither the array of "screws" or the array of "holes" can be sorted.  I think that means that you have to compare a given "screw" with each "hole" in turn in order to find a match.  That's `O(N^2)`.

There might be a better solution, but it is likely to entail changing the constraints on your problem.  In particular, the constraint that says you cannot compare "screws" or "holes" is a show stopper.  Without the ability to at least partially order the screws or the holes, I think you've got no alternative but to test the pairings one at a time.

**EDIT**

Your statement that you can determine if a "screw" is bigger or smaller than a "hole" doesn't help.  Specifically, knowing that a "hole" is too small or too big doesn't help you find a "hole" that is closer in size.

[That is ... unless you sort all "holes" according to whether they are smaller, bigger or a fit for a given "screw".  But that is an `O(N)` operation ... a bucket sort ... and you need to do that for each screw, so you are back to `O(N^2)`.  I suppose that this approach might help if you were doing this pairing process incrementally.  But you didn't say that.]

Maybe the solution to this problem is to figure out an artificial ordering on the those properties of the "holes" and "screws" that determine whether they match.  So for example, one might order the screws by a hash of the diameter and thread pitch.

Comment: wouldn't that proposed sorting be more of a variant of quicksort aka O(N*log(N) )then O(N^2). As I see it you would take an screw, sort the holes into smaller, equal and bigger, then take the equal hole to sort the screws into smaller, equal (ok we know the answer here) and bigger and now you have to smaller arrays which can each be recursivly sorted, giving us an divide&conquer approach.

Comment: @Grizzly : I'm talking about doing this sort *for each screw*; N times quicksort would be `O(N*N*log(N))`.